# Terraform load authorized_keys from Azure Keyvault > pfx certificate

Tags: openssl, terraform, azure-keyvault, terraform-provider-azure

I have followed below steps to generate pfx file and uploaded to azure keyvault, I am unable reference `authorized_key` from pfx file using terraform into my linux box while creating, am I doing something wrong way ?

```
> openssl genrsa -out private.pem 2048
> openssl req -sha256 -new -key private.pem -out csr.pem
> openssl x509 -req -sha256 -days 365 -in csr.pem -signkey private.pem -out certificate.pem
> openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey private.pem -in certificate.pem -out certificate.pfx
```

Comment: whats the error you are getting ?

Comment: I don't know how to reference this during linux machine creation.

Comment: look at this example, it may help : https://github.com/hashicorp/boundary-reference-architecture/blob/eae5f4c368dfad17be3488b925045e03b9eff8ad/deployment/azure/azure/vm.tf

Comment: he is using key_vault_keys i am using azurerm_key_vault_certificate

Comment: currently what i have done is created public and private key as secret and used public key in key_data in terraform and try to connect to  sever using private key secret it allow me to login. but it is not extracting private key from pfx cert file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I don't find anything which can use a pfx certificate as SSH key, I tried and create a private key using OpelSSL and generate authorized_key using PuttyGen and created Azure KeyVault Secrets and then reference the public key into linux SSH_Key Data. while the private key is use to access through bastion.

```
Generate a private key using OpenSSL. (will use as Bastion host ssh private key from keyvault)
> openssl genrsa -out private.pem 2048
Open PuttyGen to Generate, 
Authorized_Key (will be place in Linux box while creating., .ssh/authorized_keys)
```

```
data "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "example" {
  name         = "my-public-key"
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.existing.id


}

module "testlinux" {
  source              = "../../modules/linux"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.main.name
  vm_hostname         = "vm-linux-01"
  nb_instances        = 1
  nb_public_ip        = 0
  remote_port         = "22"
  admin_username      = var.admin_username
  vm_os_publisher     = "OpenLogic"
  vm_os_offer         = "CentOS"
  vm_os_sku           = "7.5"
  vm_size             = "Standard_D2as_v4"
  ssh_key             = data.azurerm_key_vault_secret.example.value
  vnet_subnet_id      = data.azurerm_subnet.my-subnet-01.id
  tags                = var.tags

}
```